# MSI: list required CAB files

Tags: windows, windows-installer, extract, cab

If I try to extract a certain file:

```
lessmsi x windows%20sdk%20desktop%20libs%20x64-x86_en-us.msi
```

I get this message:

```
Error: System.Exception: The file
"C:\sdk\58314d0646d7e1a25e97c902166c3155.cab" does not exist.
```

Fair enough, but does LessMsi or some other tool have a way to list all the
files that are required?

Answer (score 1):

This seems to do it:

```sh
lessmsi l -t Component sunday.msi | sed '
/dirCatalogRepositoryDirectory/!d
s/sca//
s/,.*//
'
```

Comment: Could you possibly expand on what the actual changes you made were and how they helped you? This will help others in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to do this, using Python:

```py
import msilib
path = 'Windows SDK for Windows Store Apps Headers-x86_en-us.msi'
db = msilib.OpenDatabase(path, msilib.MSIDBOPEN_DIRECT)
view = db.OpenView('SELECT * FROM Media')
view.Execute(None)

while True:
   rec = view.Fetch()
   if rec is None:
      break
   cabinet = rec.GetString(4)
   print(cabinet)
```

https://docs.microsoft.com/windows/win32/msi/media-table